# SQL Query to get all Products?

Tags: commerce

I have been given a broken site and a database that was formerly running Drupal commerce via Commerce kickstart. The site was hacked when Drupalgeddon happened, and I can't get the code to update (lots of missing component errors).

So I think we need to start over from scratch here, and I would like to know what the SQL query might be to get all of the product data out of the database? Is this something that can be done directly in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use entity field query and field api.

Something like this should be pretty easy to recover your products

```
$query=new EntityFieldQuery;
$query= $query->entityCondition('entity_type','commerce_product')->execute();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy solution for this since the field data is stored in multiple tables and is based on configuration which is also stored in the DB.

You're better off trying to use [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) and [Commerce Repair](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_repair) to get the site working and then using export tools to get the data.